# What does UTC-12 timezone mean for a submission deadline?

Tags: publications, deadlines

I look at this website: https://time.is/UTC-12

and it tells me that there's a 6 hour time difference between UTC-12 and ET.

I know about an AoE timezone that as long as it's xPM in any part of the world you are still within the deadline. Is this the same? I would really appreciate a quick response for this short question.