# What does "All deadlines are: 11:59 PM UTC-12:00" mean?

Tags: conference, paper-submission, deadlines

For example, what would this be for July 1st, 2020, in New York (Eastern Time)?

Is UTC-12 the same as AoE ("Anywhere on Earth")?

Comment: there you go https://www.thetimezoneconverter.com/

Comment: I feel this is off-topic as it has nothing to do with academia and everything to do with understanding timezones (i.e. [programming on a boat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about)).

Comment: @Conrad On the other hand, it's a deadline format that people in academia might encounter more often than others, given the international nature of most conferences/submissions.

Comment: [Merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question) answers from [What does UTC-12 timezone mean for a submission deadline?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/143254/what-does-utc-12-timezone-mean-for-a-submission-deadline) to here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does UTC-12 timezone mean for a submission deadline?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/143254/what-does-utc-12-timezone-mean-for-a-submission-deadline)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"[UTC-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9212:00)" is a timezone 12 hours behind [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), which is (more or less) the time in Greenwich, UK. Nobody actually lives there, though.

A day is 24 hours, and the Earth is divided into 27 major timezones from UTC-12 to UTC+14<sup>1</sup>, with the UK in the middle(ish). Therefore, someone in UTC-12 is the very last person to reach a time. At the time it is 12:01 AM UTC-12, it's 12:01 PM UTC+0, and 11:01 PM UTC+11.

So by setting the submission deadline to 11:59 PM UTC-12 on a given day, it ensures that anyone anywhere in the world who submits on the appropriate **day** will be on time. Hence, "[anywhere on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anywhere_on_Earth)."

New York is UTC-4 during the summer, which means the deadline is 7:59 AM the following day.

---

<sup>1</sup>: It would seem like only 24 timezones would be necessary, but a few regions chose to move to UTC+13 and UTC+14 for their own reasons. Someone in UTC+13 is 25 hours ahead of UTC-12 (so 1:01 AM the next day). The details aren't important, but in case you'd like to do your own reading.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110172/discussion-on-answer-by-azor-ahai-he-him-what-does-all-deadlines-are-1159).

Answer (score 19):

UTC-12 means that it's 12 hours behind UTC. That's the maximum distance in our 24 hour day clock. So UTC-12 is the timezone where calendars end.

That's probably the motivation behind using it as a deadline. For example, if the deadline is January 31st UTC-12, then as soon as it's not January anymore anywhere, the deadline has passed.

---

> Is UTC-12 the same as AoE ("Anywhere on Earth")?

AoE could be interpreted to apply daylight savings time. UTC *never* applies daylight savings time.

Comment: note that while UTC-12 is the maximum distance in that direction, going the other direction there is an UTC+14 timezone, meaning there's actually a 26 hour difference between the two ends of the timezone map

Comment: @SztupY I didn't know that, but [reading about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00) it's pretty interesting.

Comment: (+1) For those of us more geographically minded, this time zone is in the central Pacific, and is two hours behind Honolulu Standard Time.

Answer (score 19):

Since UTC-12:00 is the [westernmost/'latest' timezone on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#List_of_UTC_offsets), this is indeed another way to denote 'Anywhere on Earth'.

Eastern Standard Time (EST) is not used in New York on July 1st; instead, they use [Eastern Daylight Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) which is UTC-04:00, so July 1st 11:59PM UTC-12:00 is July 2nd 7:59AM EDT.

Comment: I learned this in doing my own research: "Latest" may be confusing; as the time in UTC-12 is the earliest within a given day (see how Wiki refers to UTC+14: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00).

Comment: That's why it is in quotes; 'latest' as in 'the last timezone to reach a certain date/time'.

Comment: Note that Wikipedia refers to both UTC+14 and UTC-12 as the earliest and latest timezone: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9212:00 ...